# ¿Como colocar los barcos enemigos (CPU)? Juego Battleship

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Estoy aprendiendo por mi cuenta C++.

Quisiera colocar aleatoriamente las posiciones de los barcos enemigos (obviamente que sean invisibles para mi).

El PROBLEMA es que no pude introducirlos dentro del mapa.
Tengo un par de e ideas que voy implementar, pero me gustaría su ayuda con barcos de más de una casilla. Añadiré la idea que tengo.

De paso, quisiera disparar a la cordenada/mapa (el char) que yo ponga la "X",  por medio de una tecla (Barra espaciadora), aunque ya se cómo hacer que sea sencible a teclas, no estoy seguro de como hacer la condición "si se presiona dicha letra, se imprime en el mapa un blanco o un fallo, manteniendose impreso en el mapa permanente.

Me he encontrado muchos battleship por internet, pero ninguno se asemeja a lo que trato de hacer. Tambien he notado otras formas de poner el tablero, pero esta fue la mejor para mis pocas skills de C++/programacion.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;


int delay(clock_t);
int gotoxy(int, int);
int intro(int);
int ingresar(int);

char mapa[14][22] = {
    "==================",
    "#X               #",
    "#                #",
    "#                #",
    "#                #",
    "#                #",
    "#                #",
    "#                #",
    "#                #",
    "#                #",
    "#                #",
    "=================="
};

int x=1;
int y=1;

bool juego = true;


int main(){
    int i, j, k=0;
    
    intro(i);
    gotoxy(30, 0);
    
while( juego == true){
        system("cls");
        cout << "\t\t\t\t   =========BATTLESHIP=========\n";
        for(int pantalla=0; pantalla<12; pantalla++){
            cout <<"\t\t\t\t\t" <<mapa[pantalla] << endl;
        }

        system("pause>nul");

        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN)){
            int y2 = y+1;
            if(mapa[y2][x] == ' '){
                mapa[y][x] = ' ';
                y++;
                mapa[y][x] = 'X';
            }
        }

        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP)){
            int y2 = y-1;
            if(mapa[y2][x] == ' '){
                mapa[y][x] = ' ';
                y--;
                mapa[y][x] = 'X';
            }
        }

        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT)){
            int x2 = x+1;
            if(mapa[y][x2] == ' '){
                mapa[y][x] = ' ';
                x++;
                mapa[y][x] = 'X';
            }
        }

        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT)){
            int x2 = x-1;
            if(mapa[y][x2] == ' '){
                mapa[y][x] = ' ';
                x--;
                mapa[y][x] = 'X';
            }
        }

        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE)){
            juego = false;
        }
    }
    
    system("cls");
    cout << "GAME OVER";

    return 0;
    
    
}



//AQUI


int intro(int i){
    char in1[20]="Battleship", in2[20]="Marco Molina";
    gotoxy(30, 10);
    for(i=0; in1[i]; i++){
        cout << in1[i];
        delay(100);
    }
    cout << "\n";
    gotoxy(27, 11);
    for(i=0; in2[i]; i++){
        cout << in2[i];
        delay(100);
    }
    
    system("cls");
}


int ingresar(int i);

int delay(clock_t a){
    clock_t start;
    start  = clock();
    while(clock()-start<a){}
}

int gotoxy(int x, int y){
    HANDLE hcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD dwPos;
    dwPos.X = x;
    dwPos.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hcon, dwPos);
}
```

Comment: Por qué tantos tags? No veo cómo tiene que ver con C#.

Comment: Gracias por la indicacion, pero era necesario darle una negativa?

Comment: Pues, no me preguntes a mí. Yo no la puse. Lamentablemente es costumbre dejar votos negativos sin explicación.

Comment: Cual es el problema particular que tuviste para poner los barcos? tu negativo podria venir por ese lado, porque no queda claro cual es tu problema... probaste poner el barco y paso algo? o que?

Comment: Hombre, hoy revisando me topo con esto, y me pregunto: Como quedo tu programa al final?

Comment: @Pablochaches Estuve mucho tiempo haciéndolo, pero está plataforma es muy tóxica, no vuelvo a subir mi trabajo aquí.

Comment: @MarcoMolina Hombre, entendo que no sea completamente amigable para los novatos. Como se tiene la politica de que tienes que demostrar esfuerzo de tu parte para que te ayuden, y que tienes que dar un ejemplo minimo, y verificable (Que al final llegar a ese ejemplo para hacer la pregunta es un proceso largo), se puede sentir un poco rudo cuando te mandan a volar. Hay que tomar en cuenta que aqui se toma tiempo libre para ayudar a otros. Igual de todos modos, si te topas con cualquier problema, por aqui estamos para ayudar. Suerte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para colocar los barcos en posiciones al azar en el mapa, puedes crear las posiciones con la función `rand`.
Veo que tu mapa tiene un largo de 16 caracteres y un alto de 10. Así que podrías generar las posiciones de los barcos de esta manera:

```
// Necesitas
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

// Llamas solo una vez al principio del programa:
srand(time(NULL));

/*
 * Con este vas a darle una semilla al generador de numeros,
 * asi tendras numeros diferentes cada vez.
 *
 */

// Las posiciones al azar
int barcoX = (rand() % 16) + 1;
int barcoY = (rand() % 10) +1;
```

Ahora si quieres barcos mas largos, puedes darle desde esa posición al azar y alargarlos, siempre revisando que no se salga del mapa